# PHP: Date format conversting string 2010-09-02T09:46:48.78 to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, datetime, date-formatting

I am pulling a date string from an API. The returned string looks like this:

```
2010-09-02T09:46:48.78
```

I want to convert it to 02/09/2010 (dd/mm/yyyy) but

```
date_format($note['createdate'], "d/m/Y")
```

Results in error:

```
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in
```

Can someone steer me in the right dirtection,

ta,

Jonesy

Comment: As the message specifies: you need to give a DateTime object as parameter to date_format()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime('2010-09-02T09:46:48.78'));
```

Why make it complicated ?!

Answer (score 4):

```
date_format(new DateTime($note['createdate']), "d/m/Y")
```

or use strtotime as MatTheCat showed you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple technics for this. But most useful is this.

```
   $dateRegistered = $row['registracion_date'];
   $formatDate = DATE_FORMAT(new DateTime($dateRegistered), 'd.m.Y г.');
```

Hope this helped a lot of guys out there. Cheers. @Vaseto.tk :)